# convert one big quote to string/list in scheme

Tags: scheme, y-combinator, racket

i have this assignment to do, where i need to parse a wrong written recursive procedure, and fix it.
for example:
This:

```
(let ((fib (lambda (n) 
             (cond    ((= n 0) 1) 
                         ((= n 1) 1) 
                        (else (+ (fib (- n 1)) (fib (- n 2))))))))
           (fib n))
```

Transform to this:

```
(let ((fib (lambda (n fib-param) 
                    (cond ((= n 0) 1) 
                              ((= n 1) 1) 
                             (else (+ (fib-param (- n 1) fib-param)  
                                      (fib-param (- n 2) fib-param))))))) 
  (fib n fib))
```

The procedure is given as a quote with 3 parts: the "let" , the  of the let, and the body. 
i want to parse the second part (meaning, i want to make a list that every term in it will be a single word from the expression of the "let") but i cant seem to work it out, no matter what i tried.

I'm using drRacket scheme.

Thanks and sorry for the long message.

Comment: `s/let/letrec/` ;p Hint: This is the Y combinator.

Comment: Will you forgive me if i say i didn't understand your answer? :D
I'm kinda new to scheme...

Comment: It is not an answer, it is a comment :) The first part was joke (albeit a working solution, to just replace `let` with `letrec`).

Comment: i would love to do it, but it's for a course in the university and the output should be exactly as they asked,just like the example i gave you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to read: http://www.dreamsongs.com/Files/WhyOfY.pdf, which explains how to do this transformation.  Your assignment is a classic programming languages technique for doing recursion with procedure application alone.